# take part of url use for cssSelector

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

I have this url:

```
<a href="/products/activeplug/7505c4d5-e288-40e3-8e43">
```

I want to use it only part `a[href=\"/products/"]` for cssSelector to cut `activeplug/7505c4d5-e288-40e3-8e43`.

I thought that I can use `*` after `products/*` but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the "starts with" CSS selector here:

```
a[href^="/products/"]
```